# Implement Remember me using asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry I am asking a question that has been asked before but in spite of reading all of them, I am still confused what to do. What exactly I have to do to implement the remember me feature in my website . Is calling the function "setcookie()" alone sufficient

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Identity ?

Comment: No . i m not using asp.net identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using identity, then you may need to use cookies for that.

> 1. Keep a checkbox in login page for `Remember me`.
> 2. If the checkbox is checked, keep a cookie with some identifier which is in turn stored to the db.
> 3. Next time when anyone comes to the login page, check for this cookie identifer in the database and if it exists, login
>      automatically.

You can read more by doing a quick search on how to remember user using cookies.